# Can I force flutter Text widget to take blank characters into account when being laid out

Tags: flutter

I have a bunch of text widgets evenly spaced in a row. The text values for each text can change from 0 to 100. When The values change, the other Text widget adjust positions in thw row as the size for the individual text widgets change.

For example, when the left most widgets text changes from 100 to 0 (aka 3 digits to 1 digit) all the other text move over a litte.

I want to stop this. I want the spacing to be constanst.

I tried padding all of the string (with whitespace) so all the text have a 3 digit string. But it seems like the Text widget is culling all the leading and trailing whitespace.

Is there a way I can have text not cull the whitespace?

Or is there a way I can have text in fixed positions in a row?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a suggestion. You could put each `Text` widget inside a `SizedBox` widget with a fixed width.

```
var itemWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / noOfItems;
```

`MediaQuery.of(context).size` gets the dimensions of the screen.

You might want to use [AutoSizeText](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_size_text) to stop the text flowing outside of the bounds of the box, if it doesn't fit.

Another suggestion that might help, depending on what you're making is to use `DataTable` [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DataTable-class.html)